# Collect values from list of POJO using Functional interfaces (lambdas)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How can I iterate over list of POJO classes for collecting result of some methods in a standard way to avoid copy past?
I want to have code like this:

```
//class 'Person' has methods: getNames(), getEmails()
List<Person> people = requester.getPeople(u.getId());
String names = merge(people, Person::getNames);
String emails = merge(people, Person::getEmails);
```

instead of such copy-pasted logic:

```
List<Person> people = requester.getPeople(u.getId());
Set<String> namesAll = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> emailsAll = new HashSet<>();
for (Person p : people) {
   if(p.getNames()!=null) {
      phonesAll.addAll(p.getNames());
   }
   if(p.getEmails()!=null) {
      emailsAll.addAll(p.getEmails());
   }
}
String names = Joiner.on(", ").skipNulls().join(namesAll);
String emails = Joiner.on(", ").skipNulls().join(emailsAll);
```

Thus, is it possible to implement some standard approach for iterating and processing special method of POJO in list that could be reused?

Comment: The code in merge() would be similar to the one you have in the second snippet: it would loop over the persons, would get the names or the emails by calling the `Function<Person, Collection<String>>` that is passed as the second argument of merge(), and then join them. Have you tried anything? What's the difficulty you're facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this :

```
String names = people.stream().flatMap(p->p.getNames().stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Now, if you want to save typing that line for each property, you can have this `merge` method as you suggested :

```
public static String merge (List<Person> people, Function<Person, Collection<String>> mapper)
{
    return people.stream().flatMap(p->mapper.apply(p).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

This would make your first snippet work.

Now, you can make this method generic :

```
public static <T> String merge (List<T> list, Function<T, Collection<String>> mapper)
{
    return list.stream().flatMap(p->mapper.apply(p).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

I think this should work (haven't tested it).

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eran - Out of curiosity:- isn't this way we are running for loops two times instead of one time as in OP's code?

Comment: @Jags Yep, we are iterating twice over the list. That's the price you pay in this example for writing generic code.

Comment: I dont think @user_x has thought about this as he wants to use it probably for lot many properties then just 2.

Comment: @Jags this implementation is fine for me. I want to just minimize code. Performance is not an issue. If performance would be more critical, then array or list of Function<> mappers could be used.